# Can the sum of class probabilities calculated by the naive Bayes's classifier algorithm combined with Laplace smoothing be greater than 1?

Tags: python, algorithm, probability, data-mining, naivebayes

I've been trying to implement a naive Bayes' classifier algorithm **with Laplace smoothing** for my data-mining course, but I'm not sure my probabilities are correct.

Is it possible for P(C<sub>1</sub>) + P(C<sub>2</sub>) > 1.0? I'll include my inputs and arithmetic below.

```
    [k = 2 (number of classes)          |         lambda = 1 (for simplicity)]

C1 = (4 + lambda) / (4 + (k * lambda)) = 0.8333

C2 = (9 + lambda) / (9 + (k * lambda)) = 0.9000
```

Comment: No, you can never have a probability > 1. Your code might be incorrect.

Comment: @wundermahn, thanks for the comment. This is my thinking too, however I'm wondering if the Laplace smoothing (additive smoothing) is weighting the probabilities higher. Probabilities calculated via NBC don't typically add up to 1.00 anyway, but the probabilites seem to be off

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs more on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/